# SQL Agrupar mesmo ID com outra condição

Tags: sql, group-by

Acredito seja uma pergunta um pouco específica, pois não achei nada relacionado ainda.

Tenho uma tabela chamada `contas_produtos`, que é uma relação **NxN** entre as tabelas `contas` e a tabela `produtos`.

A tabela possui as seguintes colunas:

```
ID (PK)
conta_id (FK)
produto_id (FK)
precoFinal (float)
```

Pois bem, esse `precoFinal` indica o valor final de um determinado produto, que pode ser alterado pela aplicação, ou seja, dois produtos podem ter o mesmo `id`, mas com valores diferentes de `precoFinal`.

O que eu desejo fazer é conseguir agrupar os produtos de mesmo `id`, mas com preços finais iguais, e separar esses produtos dos que tem mesmo `id` mas preços finais diferentes.

Sei que não posso simplesmente agrupar por `precoFinal`, pois pegaria produtos com preços diferentes.

O que eu já fiz até agora foi agrupar por `id`, mas não me serve, portanto não compensa nem eu colocar meu SQL aqui.

Muito texto, eu sei, mas acho que ficaria mais fácil de explicar assim.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Veja se resolve

```
SELECT conta_id, 
       produto_id, 
       precofinal 
FROM   ((produtos 
         INNER JOIN contas_produtos 
                 ON id = conta_id) 
        INNER JOIN produtos 
                ON produto_id = produto_id ) 
GROUP  BY id, 
          precofinal
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta e pelo seu esforço amigo, mas acho que a solução mais fácil seria realmente o group by com dois campos. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Não por isso, o problema, mas eu coloquei o grup by com dois campos, o resto do sql so esta ai pra representa o que vc nao postou, e  como vc mesmo disse que existe uma relação de NxN nas tabelas mencionadas, o correto é se usar o inner join nestes casos, a unica diferença entre nossas respostas é a sintaxe. mas de qualquer forma boa sorte !

Answer (score -2):

Bom, eu peço desculpas, eu consegui resolver apenas usando o group by com mais de uma coluna, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS quantidade, 
       conta_id, 
       produto_id, 
       precofinal 
FROM   conta_produtos 
GROUP  BY produto_id, 
          precofinal
```

Comment: Otimo boa sorte !

Comment: Desculpa, mas por que -2 ? Nao deveria ter respondido minha propria pergunta? Como proceder neste caso?